# Script does not run on IE after deferring parsing of javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, seo

In a bid to optimize my pages, i wanted to defer parsing of javascript. I put the code below for my facebook like box in the head portion of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function downloadJSAtOnload() {
   var element = document.createElement("script");
   element.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
   document.body.appendChild(element); 
 } 
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Now on works well on Google Chrome and Mozilla but does not display the like box on INternet Explorer.

Please how can i fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the script loaders I've seen append the script element to the first head tag, not the body tag like is shown in [this description](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html).

```
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
   head.appendChild(script);
```

I can't say if that is what is causing your issue on IE, but it seems worth changing to.

Also, since you're waiting for the window load event, do you realize that this script won't be loaded until the last image on the page has finished downloading.  That's a lot longer than you have to wait.

As best I can tell, IE just doesn't work if the FB script is loaded after the content is loaded.  Even if you put it after the content in a traditional script tag, it doesn't work in IE.  It must be something about the way the facebook script works in IE.  I'm sorry I can't help more.  You can see that even that this doesn't work in IE8:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like-box href="http://facebook.com/pages/MyJobMag/165211540158300" width="336" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="true" colorscheme="light"></fb:like-box>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

But, this does work in IE8:

P.S. You have an extraneous semicolon in your HTML after the URL, but removing it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks, i modified it; it still shows in chrome and mozilla but still doesnt show in internet explorer.

Comment: It also occurs to me that if the Facebook script is also waiting for the load event and you don't load the script until after that event fires, it could mess up the script.

Comment: When are you calling any FB functions?  Are you waiting until the FB script is loaded?

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to fix this yet optimizing page load?

Comment: i have this on the body of my page (like box): <div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/MyJobMag/165211540158300" width="336" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="true" colorscheme="light"></fb:like-box>

Comment: I added some more info into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

After i read through the [facebook dev reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). I made a [demo](http://jsbin.com/onehul/17) for you. You can aslo edit the code at http://jsbin.com/onehul/17/edit.

Basically, you need add xml name space at html documentElement

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This ensure the browser will accept and parse the non-standard tag from facebook,
and then dynamiclly create the script tag appending to `fb-root` div.finally, do cleaning up. After the script successfully loaded,remove it from the dom tree.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root">
  </div>
  <script>

  var script,
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0] || document.documentElement;

script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.async = "async";
script.charset = "utf-8";
script.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";

// Attach handlers for all browsers
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (!script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test( script.readyState ) ) {

         // Handle memory leak in IE
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;

        // Remove the script
        if ( head && script.parentNode ) {
            head.removeChild( script );
        }

        // Dereference the script
        script = undefined;
   }
};

// Use insertBefore instead of appendChild  to circumvent an IE6 bug.
// This arises when a base node is used (#2709 and #4378).
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(script);
  </script>

  <fb:like-box href="http://facebook.com/pages/MyJobMag/165211540158300" width="336" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="true" colorscheme="light"></fb:like-box>
</body>
</html>
```

The code below is borrow and modified from jquery source code to load script dynamiclly, which should works under all browser

```
var script,
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0] || document.documentElement;

script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.async = "async";
script.charset = "YOUR SCRIPT CHARSET";
script.src = "YOUR SCRIPT SRC";

// Attach handlers for all browsers
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (!script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test( script.readyState ) ) {

         // Handle memory leak in IE
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;

        // Remove the script
        if ( head && script.parentNode ) {
            head.removeChild( script );
        }

        // Dereference the script
        script = undefined;

   };
}

// Use insertBefore instead of appendChild  to circumvent an IE6 bug.
// This arises when a base node is used (#2709 and #4378).
head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
```

Comment: We don't actually think the issue is about getting the script loaded properly.  It appears to be a load timing issue.